# Difference between desktop-install and copying desktop file to applications directory

Tags: launcher, shortcuts, .desktop

When we want to add a shortcut to menu. We can do that by creating `filename.desktop` and copy that file to `/usr/share/applications`. And there is another way to, that is doing `desktop-file-install filename.desktop`. What is difference between those two?

Until now, I still use `copy` method because if I want to remove it, i just delete it. And `desktop-file-install` seems like doesn't have `desktop-file-uninstall`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quote `man desktop-file-install`:

> `desktop-file-install` will always try to validate the resulting desktop file. A failure to validate might lead to the abortion of the installation of the desktop files.

In contrast, `cp` will copy anything.

So there is no `desktop-file-uninstall` since there is no need to validate files you are deleting.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but the answer was either incomplete or has changed over time.

`desktop-file-install` causes a database update, and to be precise, it updates the cache by `rebuild_cache()`.
More details can be found in the source, in the official repository "desktop-file-utils":
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xdg/desktop-file-utils/-/blob/master/src/install.c#L291

Just copying with `cp` does not cause the mime base to be updated, which is important - it does not update its cache.
**This is important for file updating** - you may notice that if you change the text of the *.desktop on path `/usr/share/xfce4/helpers/` file itself, the changes will not be accepted immediately.

The install call will do:

- First validation of the *.desktop file by `desktop-file-validate`
- Further, if the file is valid, it will update the database by calling the `update-desktop-database` command