# Trouble installing Android Studio

Tags: software-installation, android-studio

After installing android studio and running all the commands in terminal and saving the text editor ".desktop'' file..terminal is showing the following error:

```
~/Downloads$ cd ~/Downloads
~/Downloads$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for arpit
~# mv android-studio /opt
mv: cannot stat 'android-studio': No such file or directory
~# gedit android-studio.desktop
desktop-file-install android-studio.desktop

~# desktop-file-install android-studio.desktop
Error on file "android-studio.desktop": Key file does not start with a group

~# desktop-file-install android-studio.desktop
Error on file "android-studio.desktop": Key file does not start with a group
~# ^C
~#
```

Comment: Two items:  First, it is preferable to copy the text from your terminal into your question, rather than pasting a picture of your screen.  Secondly, you might find [https://askubuntu.com/questions/601000/difference-between-desktop-install-and-copying-desktop-file-to-applications-dire](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601000/difference-between-desktop-install-and-copying-desktop-file-to-applications-dire) to help you in getting your .desktop file to work.

Answer (score 0):

The official Ubuntu way to install Android studio is this:

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-make
$ sudo umake android
```

Comment: it is showing this error-  arpit@arpit-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$  sudo apt install ubuntu-make
[sudo] password for arpit: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-make
arpit@arpit-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo umake android
sudo: umake: command not found
arpit@arpit-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: You may need to enable universe repo from software and updates first. Here is the package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/ubuntu-make